# How can we configure VS2012 to auto format <tabset> and <tab> elements used in Angularjs-ui?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

We have tried on two machines now to set up VS2012 to recognize the `<tabset>` and `<tab>` elements. If we wrote our own directives we would probably need to get it to recognize others.  We go to the formatting /validation menu. Set up everything but then when we try to format the code it still does not seem to recognize the new elements we added. Are we missing something. Has it been done by others ?